# Problems sending email using QT via SMTP

Tags: qt, smtp, mailing

I think am having trouble in the library i was told to add **libcrypto-1_1.dll** **libeay32.dll** and **libssl-1_1.dll** in the Debug folder of my project . Also i added network in my .pro file but still don't know what's going wrong.

[image]

This is my output:

```
StateChanged QAbstractSocket::HostLookupState
StateChanged QAbstractSocket::ConnectingState
StateChanged QAbstractSocket::ConnectedState
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSLv23_client_method
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_CTX_new
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function SSL_library_init
qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function ERR_get_error
Error QAbstractSocket::SocketError(21)
Qt.network.ssl: QSslSocket: cannot call unresolved function  ERR_get_error
Error QAbstractSocket::SocketError(20)
Connected
Error QAbstractSocket:: RemoteHostClosedError
StateChanged QAbstractSocket::ClosingState
StateChanged QAbstractSocket::UnconnectedState
Disconnected
Error "The remote host closed the connection
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your error messages as text instead of as an image.

Comment: Hello, i just editted my question i pasted the output

Comment: Adding dlls to your executable folder is not the normal way to link with libraries. Normally the libraries are installed somewhere on your system and you pass linker arguments telling it where to look for them.

Comment: Do you know where or how?

Comment: That depends on your OS and compiler. I use Linux with gcc, so the default location for libraries is /usr/lib. If I want to link with something there, I'd add the `-lmyLibrary` compiler flag. If the library is installed somewhere else, then I need to tell the compiler about that. `-L/path/to/my/lib -lmyLibrary`.